# Too much information

Tags: list, scala

I have this code running fine but then it shows too much information and I only want the last line in the code.

Code here:

```
import scala.io.Source

object CovidWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val filename = Source.fromFile("OOPAssignment3.txt")


    try{
        for (line <- filename.getLines.toList) {
            if (line.contains("Malaysia") && line.split(",").apply(7).nonEmpty) {
                val allDeathString: String = line.split(",").apply(7)
                print("\n\n Malaysia latest total amount of death: " + allDeathString)
            }
        }
    }
    finally{
        filename.close
        //print("\nThe file is now closed")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result I obtain from it.[result of the running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkwF.png)

I just want the last line of the information instead of the entire thing. Anyone can figure out how? Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Can you not just print in the `finally` part instead of the `for` loop?  Declare` allDeathSring` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here. What is in that OOPAssignement3.txt file ? Do you want to add these death-counts to calculate all-deaths-count in "Malaysia" ? And then print that all-deaths-count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the inside of your `try` block with:

```
 filename
      .getLines
      .filter(line => line.contains("Malaysia") && line.split(",").apply(7).nonEmpty)
      .toList
      .takeRight(1)
      .foreach(line => {
        val allDeathString: String = line.split(",").apply(7)
        print("\n\n Malaysia latest total amount of death: " + allDeathString)
      })
```

The key part for your purposes is `takeRight` which selects `n` elements from the end of the list. When `n == 1` you're taking only the last match which is what you want here.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it has helped me so much :))))